# Why is Giit `credential.<URL>` with `useHttpPath` not treated correctly?

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I have the following in my global gitconfig

```ini
[credential "https://git.server.com"]
    useHttpPath = true
```

and a credential entry to the Git credential manager with

```bash
echo -n "protocol=https\nhost=git.server.com\npath=/repos/myrepo2.git\nusername=bla\npassword=mypass1\n" | git credential approve

echo -n "protocol=https\nhost=git.server.com\npath=/repos/myrepo2.git\nusername=bla\npassword=mypass2\n" | git credential approve
```

Because I want to use exacly this two credential for the URLs the `git credential fill`

```bash
echo -n "protocol=https\nhost=git.server.com\npath=/repos/myrepo1.git\nusername=bla\n" | git credential fill

echo -n "protocol=https\nhost=git.server.com\npath=/repos/myrepo2.git\nusername=bla\n" | git credential fill
```

works and returns `password=mypass1` and `mypass2`.
When I however use `/repos` in the config

```ini
[credential "https://git.server.com/repos"]
    useHttpPath = true
```

the `useHttpPath` is not picked up for

```bash
echo -n "protocol=https\nhost=git.server.com\npath=/repos/myrepo1.git\nusername=bla" | git credential fill
```

and therefore I get `mypass2` as result.

Is this a Git bug? Documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential#IOFMT